# Why does Simplify not reduce the expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a long expression and it includes some terms with long polynomial coefficients.

For example,

```
expression = 
  Log[a] (48 A ((2 - 4 a + 3 a^2) eA F^2 + A eF ((2 - 4 a + a^2) A - 4 (-1 + a)^2 F)) - (-1 + a) A^2 Log[a/(-1 + a)]^2 (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R
+ 657 a^5 R - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b]) - 2 (-1 + a) A F Log[a/(-1 + a)] Log[(-1 + a)/b] (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R
+ 657 a^5 R - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b]) - (-1 + a) F^2 Log[(-1 + a)/b]^2 (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R + 657 a^5 R
- 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b]));
```

where all parameters are positive with `a>1`. I try to `Simplify` it with

```
Simplify[expression, {Positive[R], Positive[A], Positive[F], Positive[eA], Positive[eF], Positive[b]}, Assumptions -> a > 1]
```

but it returns the same expression. Obviously, there are three terms multiplied by the same polynomial `(A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R + 657 a^5 R - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b])`. But I don't know how to tell Mathematica to understand this.

I found with the first term in the parentheses absent, Mathematica knows how to do this. But in my real problem, I have a long expression with many instances like the abovementioned. Thank you very much!

```
expression2 = Log[a] ((*48 A ((2 - 4 a + 3 a^2) eA F^2 + A eF ((2 - 4 a + a^2) A - 4 (-1 + a)^2 F))*) - (-1 + a) A^2 Log[a/(-1 + a)]^2 (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R
    + 657 a^5 R - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b]) - 2 (-1 + a) A F Log[a/(-1 + a)] Log[(-1 + a)/b] (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R
    + 657 a^5 R - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b]) - (-1 + a) F^2 Log[(-1 + a)/b]^2 (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R + 657 a^5 R
    - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b]));

Simplify[expression2, {Positive[R], Positive[A], Positive[F], Positive[eA], Positive[eF], Positive[b]}, Assumptions -> a > 1]

(*-(-1 + a) Log[a] (A Log[a/(-1 + a)] + F Log[(-1 + a)/b])^2 (A (-96 + 192 a + 420 a^3 R - 779 a^4 R + 657 a^5 R - 243 a^6 R + 29 a^7 R - 12 a^2 (4 + 7 R)) + 12 (-1 + a)^3 a^2 (7 - 14 a + 3 a^2) F R Log[b])*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FullSimplify:

```
FullSimplify[expression, {Positive[R], Positive[A], Positive[F], 
  Positive[eA], Positive[eF], Positive[b], a > 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried `FullSimplify` but it runs for a very long time before aborting manually. Is there any other method?

Comment: It takes 2.5 sec on my 5 year old machine.